# Can I use the servlet style paramerters in Ajax

Tags: ajax, servlets

I had a server request to `http://ixxxp/abc.action?param:{userId:1234}` to get some information about the user. And I use jQuery Ajax to request this info.

When I test through `curl` or other browser client, I was curious about the param list. How can a server page receive this url request? Shouldn't it be like:

```
http:// ixxxp/abc.action?userId=1234 //-------------------------1
```

Or

```
http:// ixxxp/abc.action?param={userId:1234}//------------------2
```

But `1` returns `{}` which is definitely not true. `1234` is a test user, and he has some information predifined.

The final question is : **How can I request this servlet in Ajax, because jQuery will generate a url like 1 which doesn't work in my situation**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your first question: The application must have some sort of reading mechanism that reads the URL (Query_String) and then breaking it up into parameters.

About your second question, I guess you can do it like this:

```
function getUser(userId){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'abc.action?param={userId:'+userId+'}',
        data: {
        },
        beforeSend:function(){
        },
        success:function(data){
        },
        error:function(){
        }
    });
}
```